# CSharpCodeProvider doesn't return compiler warnings when there are no errors

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, compiler-construction, .net-4.0

I'm using the `CSharpCodeProvider` class to compile a C# script which I use as a DSL in my application. When there are warnings but no errors, the `Errors` property of the resulting `CompilerResults` instance contains no items. But when I introduce an error, the warnings suddenly get listed in the `Errors` property as well.

```
string script = @"
    using System;
    using System; // generate a warning
    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
            public void MyMethod()
            {
                // uncomment the next statement to generate an error
                //intx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
";

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }
    });

CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    compilerParameters,
    script);

foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
{
    Console.Write(error.IsWarning ? "Warning: " : "Error: ");
    Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
}
```

So how to I get hold of the warnings when there are no errors?
By the way, I don't want to set `TreatWarningsAsErrors` to `true`.

Comment: btw, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610886/is-it-possible-to-call-c-lexical-syntactic-analyzers-without-compilation/2611177#2611177 about `GenerateInMemory`

Comment: @abatishchev thanks, that's an interesting fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `CompilerParameters.WarningLevel`

Comment: I tried that already but it didn't make any difference. Besides, the warnings do get reported if there is at least an error. That wouldn't happen if the warning level was set to an inappropriate level.

Comment: So it turns out you were right after all, I had to set the warning level to 3 (I guess I only tried 0, 1 and perhaps 2). Because you were the first to suggest this, I accepted your answer.

Comment: @Sandor: Thank you! As far as I could understand from Reflector `WarningLevel` is being set by default to `4`. But in MSDN nothing is said about that,

Answer (score 1):

It worked fine for me, after I fixed the other compile errors in your code (The comment characters) and set `compilerParameters.WarningLevel`.

Comment: Thanks, setting it to 3 in this case appears to do the trick. I think is peculiar though that in case of one or more errors the warnings show up regardless of the warning level parameter value.