# convert a string to a linq query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

is there an easy way to convert a string to a linq query?

e.g. var query = StringToLINQQuery(AString);

has somebody the implementation for this method?

Comment: What does this string represent? SQL?

Comment: a linq query according to the ms examples, in the simplest case: from p in DB.Table select p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried already linq dynamics:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You would have to compile the string.

The [compiler as a service](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/05/11/using-c-compiler-as-a-service-in-f-poshconsole-powershell/) feature is [scheduled for C# 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210734/what-is-the-state-of-the-c-compiler-as-a-service), so it's not here yet. It's [already available](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-27.html) on Mono, but Mono's support for LINQ was quite shaky last time I checked.

Comment: @max, to my knowledge, there's no independent C# parser, so you would still need the compiler to do that.